# Add multiple values to the URL dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to make a request to an endpoint that expects only one user account Id, so I tried to separate the user account Ids (if they are multiple) by &. The `this.account` is an array with account Id strings. And this is how I am doing it but it still appends the values with a comma:

```
getAccountStats(callback) {
        
        let acc = this.account.map((val) => {
    
            if (val>1) {
                return 'accountID_'+val+'&'
            }
            return 'accountID__'+val;
        })
        let url = `/${acc}/userAccount`;
        
        axios.get(url, callback);
    }
```

When I console.log the url, it returns `/accountID_1,accountID_2/userAccount` but I want it to be `/accountID_1&accountID_2/userAccount`. Any idea how to achieve this. TIA

Comment: "I am trying to make a request to an endpoint that expects only one user account Id" If this assumption is true, it won't matter how many user ids you add. It just won't work.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Are you trying to request data for multiple users? Most likely you will need to make a request for each user unless you can find a route that allows you to send multiple ids.

Comment: Yes I am trying to request data for multiple users

Comment: If val is a string then split it. If val is an Array then use an index or may be replace comma with & sign.

Comment: @Ismail `val` is clearly an element of the `account` array. Most likely it is a string or an int with the user's id.

Comment: its a string @Ismail . the array itself would look like ['1','2']

Comment: acc = acc.join('&')  join the account with & sign. Or take one with an index. Like this  let url = `/${acc[0]}/userAccount`;

Comment: @Ismail Your suggestion will just cause more problems since it creates an invalid URL.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice please explain how? I tested it locally and it does put an & sign instead of comma.

Comment: Your first statement should be the very reason why it would not work. A request needs to meet API's expected format. I would advise you to (1) check whether the API provides a way to request multiple data in a single call or (2) make multiple calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to make a request to an endpoint that expects only one user account Id, so I tried to separate the user account Ids (if they are multiple) by &

The short answer is what you think you want won't ever work. If the endpoint only expects 1 account id, then trying to add more won't do what you want.

> but I want it to be `/accountID_1&accountID_2/userAccount`

This doesn't look like a valid endpoint. So I doubt you really want this.

Comment: If that is a valid endpoint, how do I achieve two IDs to be appended? Also is there a way where I can make multiple requests to the endpoint with one ID at a time?

Comment: "Also is there a way where I can make multiple requests to the endpoint with one ID at a time? " Yes, you can definitely make multiple requests. In this case, though, it should be to different end ponts for each user: `/accountID_1/userAccount`, `/accountID_2/userAccount/`, etc.

Comment: "If that is a valid endpoint, how do I achieve two IDs to be appended?" It's not a valid endpoint, so the question is moot.

Comment: Any idea how I should approach this problem? With only one ID it returns the data perfectly. With multiple, it returns undefined, but I need data for both the IDs

Comment: @boomchickawawa You should make a request with one id at a time. I suggest you learn about `for` loops.

Comment: I used a forEach loop to make multiple request to the endpoint with different IDs and it works perfectly. Except it throws an `Callback was already called` error. Not sure why this occurs

Comment: @boomchickawawa That sounds like a new question.